# Azure botframework integrated with Dynamics customer service Omnichannel generating same user id for different users

Tags: botframework, microsoft-dynamics

We have integrated Microsoft dynamics Customer service omnichannel with Azure botframework. The bot hosted on Azure and registered as an Agent in Omnichannel application. Omnichannel application is connected with WhatsApp using Twilio

The issue is that one chat initiated with user A from WhatsApp has the same user id for user B although user names are different
Below is the snapshot for telemetry logs from Application insights. My understanding is that if these two users are totally different then user ids should be different for each user.

**Code**
TelemetryClient.TrackEvent("ADP:User Id" + turnContext.Activity.From.Id);

TelemetryClient.TrackEvent("ADP:User Name" + turnContext.Activity.From.Name);

**User A**

User Name:+923454330135

User Id"8:acs:df6c3575-e291-4317-b2ea-917c331ecb4f_00000015-fe0a-ac34-a70b-5748220022b6"

**User B**

User Name:+923056061475

User Id"8:acs:df6c3575-e291-4317-b2ea-917c331ecb4f_00000015-fe0a-ac34-a70b-5748220022b6"